# Handle an iframe witha Selenium in java - .click() doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am starting to learn selenium to switch from manual to automatic testing.
I was following a tutorial on a website. but when I launched the script the first time, and opened [the page for the test](https://demo.guru99.com/popup.php) I discovered this cookie acceptance (sorry if it's in Italian)
[image]

After discovering that the advice was inside an iframe I rewrote the script to handle it. My idea was "Now I click on "Accept All" (Accetta tutti) and I can continue with the tutorial." Unfortunately, the click() command doesn't work.

This is my script:

```
 package newpackage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class popUpAutomation {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/ccumi/Downloads/chromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        
        chrome.get("https://demo.guru99.com/popup.php");
        chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int size= chrome.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
        System.out.println("iframe "+ size);
        
        chrome.switchTo().frame(3);

        System.out.println(chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']/span/div")).getText());
        
        chrome.findElement(By.id("save")).click();  
    }
}
```

I don't understand where is the error, because on the console I see that in this line the element is found:

```
System.out.println(chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']/span/div")).getText());
```

Comment: Put `chrome.manage().timeouts()...` before `chrome.get("https://demo.guru99.com/popup.php");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the working code below with in-line explanation:

```
chrome.get("https://demo.guru99.com/popup.php");
chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);;
int size= chrome.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
System.out.println("iframe "+ size);
        
// switch into the IFRAME with ID=gdpr-consent-notice
chrome.switchTo().frame(chrome.findElement(By.id("gdpr-consent-notice")));

System.out.println(chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']/span/div")).getText());
        
// Below 2 lines will click on the Accept All button using JavaScript
WebElement element = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']/span/div"));
((JavascriptExecutor) chrome).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

// Below line will come out of the IFRAME and switch to main HTML context 
chrome.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Console result:

```
iframe 3
Accept All
```

Comment: I'll try this evening after work. ;-) Thank you

Comment: Test it: it's work. Thanks!